# Why does IE7 compatibility back button php can't detect as IE7?

Tags: php, html, ie-compatibility-mode

I am having weird issues with IE7 Compatibility mode and HTML5.

Symptoms: Going directly to my homepage, using PHP can detect that it is IE7. After hitting a form submit button, and clicking the return back button, it no longer detects as IE7 even while still in compatibility mode. Must be refresh or reloaded to detect as IE7 again.

What can I do to make this more robust? Please don't say to use get_browser and browscap. I do not wish to keep maintain on that browscap.ini.

in the html head:

```
<?php 
    /**
    *   IE 7 has trouble with jscrollpane, so disable for all IE except for 9 which works just fine.
    */ 
    $getBrowser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
    if( (!stristr($getBrowser,'MSIE')) || stristr($getBrowser,'MSIE 9')):
?>
<script src="jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
<script src="jquery/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script  src="jquery/js.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Updated:

```
$getBrowser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
        if( stristr($getBrowser,'MSIE') === false)
```

Relocated js.js line to:

```
<!--[if IE 9 ]>
    <script  src="jquery/js.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Still does the same thing when hitting back button.

**Edit: Man.... I guess I am having some serious machine problems. The box with windows must have been screwed up after the windows update. Sorry for this crazy stuff. Works fine on another machine that has not ran windows update yet.**

Comment: This calls for basic debugging: What does `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` contain when it does not work? (It may well be that a more elegant solution exists, though)

Comment: @Pekka, your right, when I hit the back button, HTTP_USER_AGENT does not seem to pick up anything and breaks the check. I can go to any "other" page and hit the back button, and have the check for IE7 fail. I don't know any other method to check though.

Comment: that's really odd. But a conditional comment as suggested by @tradyblix should do the job

Comment: Okay, this is going to sound really odd, but diggin deeper, I found that for whatever reason, when I hit the back button, it is going back to a really old cached version of index.php. I've deleted all cache, closed and reloaded IE, but it keeps doing the same thing. WTF lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have IE9 so I can't try it but can't you do something like this and place it on the `<head>`:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
     // your includes here
<![endif]-->
```

Not sure if it matters to you to still see the `script` tags included in the source but at least it won't execute them unless the check was satisfied.

Comment: I am trying and to the most part, all of what I have working for Chrome, FF4, and IE9 works well together, but filter out for IE7 and below. And yes I have those conditions for IE7 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

As @tradyblix said, you can do this client side. They're called [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

If you have to do it in the PHP, I would use strpos().

```
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (stripos($ua, 'MSIE') === false || stripos($ua, 'MSIE 9') !== false)
```

Comment: Okay, I don't understand why that when it fails to detect as IE7, it will include only the js.js file, and none of the other mousewheel and jscrollpane.min.js. Even the HTML if condition is failing when hitting the back button.